# How to replace bbcode to tags HTML via preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have bbcodes at page:

```
[list=1]
[*]Камиль [/*]
[*]Хисматуллин [/*]
[*]живет в настоящий [/*]
[/list]
```

How I can replace these bbcodes to HTML tags:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I tried regular expression:

```
$advanced_bbcode = array(
 '#\[list=([0-9]?)](.+)\[/list]#Usi',
 '#\[*](.+)\[/*]#Usi'
);

$advanced_html = array(
   '<ol>$1</ol>',
   '<li>$1</li>'
);

$text = preg_replace($advanced_bbcode, $advanced_html,$text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the regex a bit (add the `Singleline` inline `(?s)` option that can be combined with case-insensitive `(?i)` option), the rest is neat. Only I do not know if you need `<ol>` or `<ul>` (you can adjust that part yourself). Here is my solution (tested on [TutorialsPoint](http://goo.gl/fom5rG)):

```
<?php

   $str = "[list=1]\n[*]Камиль [/*]\n[*]Хисматуллин [/*]\n[*]живет в Урюпинске [/*]\n[/list]"; 

   $advanced_bbcode = array(
     '/(?si)\\[list=\\d+\\](.*?)\\[\\/list\\]/',
     '/(?si)\\[\\*\\](.*?)\\[\\/\\*\\]/'
    );
    $advanced_html = array(
      '<ol>$1</ol>',
      '<li>$1</li>'
    );
    $text = preg_replace($advanced_bbcode, $advanced_html, $str);
    echo $text;
?>
```

Output:

```
<ol>                                                                                                                                                                
<li>Камиль </li>                                                                                                                                                    
<li>Хисматуллин </li>                                                                                                                                               
<li>живет в Урюпинске </li>                                                                                                                                         
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$advanced_bbcode = array(
  '#\[list=[0-9]+\](.+)\[\/list\]#i',
  '#\[\*\](.+)\[\/\*\]#i'
);

$advanced_html = array(
  '<ol>$1</ol>',
  '<li>$1</li>'
);

$text = preg_replace($advanced_bbcode, $advanced_html, $text);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its explanation.